# Codeigniter memory limit exceeded

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following file:

controllers/funding.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ad1cjhx
 * Date: 04/12/2014
 * Time: 09:45
 */

class Funding extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('funding');

    }

    public function index() {

        //$funding_list = $this->funding->get_all();

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('funding/list');
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }

}
```

models/funding.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ad1cjhx
 * Date: 04/12/2014
 * Time: 09:53
 */

class Funding_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function get_all() {

        //$sql = "SELECT * FROM funds LIMIT 1";

        return 1;

    }

}
```

Which return: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in /webusers/u/public_html/funding_manager/application/config/autoload.php on line 1122

The calling of the model in the constructor of the controller seems to generate an error... Any thoughts?

EDIT

Code around autoload.php 1122:

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Models
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['model'] = array('model1', 'model2');
|
*/

$autoload['model'] = array();


/* End of file autoload.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/autoload.php */
```

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Please check code for infinite loops

Comment: @Rajasekhar that is the code. The three views I'm loading are empt files.

Comment: 67Mo with only this code and empty views ? There must be a problem somewhere else at line 122 maybe. What is there ?

Comment: @BabyAzerty updated above

Comment: If your model's class name is `Funding_model`, your model's file name must be `funding_model.php`.

Comment: line `1122` ? ci autoload file is hardly `120` lines

Comment: Have you tried renaming your model file?